# How can I parse a line of potentially quoted search terms, and how can I use these terms to match input lines that each contain all of them?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, parsing, string-comparison

I'm using Bash on Mac OS X El Capitan.

My main goal:

1. Allow a user to input any number of search terms, including ones containing quotes.
2. Iterate through a text file and show the user every line that contains matches for all search terms input.

I have a text file that is essentially an index of files on various servers. E.g.,

```
/Volumes/Server1/Resources/Images/this.jpg
/Volumes/Server2/Inventory/docs/that.doc
/Volumes/Server6/Projects/Project 32/the other.pdf
/Volumes/Server6/Projects/Project 32/audio video training.doc
```

I'm using

```
read -r sSearchTerms
```

to let a user input search criteria. I basically just want to parse whatever she enters so I can allow her to search based on multiple terms. I also want to allow the use of quotes to search for terms containing spaces.

For example, a user might enter ***"Project 32" "audio video" doc***

In this case, I want to compare 3 terms to each line of my index text file: *Project 32, audio video,* and *doc*, building a results.txt file that I can then easily show the user.

The two main things I need to figure out:

1. How to parse the input line properly into separate strings to use for comparison purposes (making sure that anything inside quotes is treated as a single search term (and removing the quotes before comparing)). I'm imagining using an array?

   - `stringCompare[0]="Project 32"`
   - `stringCompare[1]="audio video"`
   - `stringCompare[2]="doc"`
2. How to properly test each line of the text file to see if it contains matches for all search terms input.

Below is my working code for comparing the whole input line as a single search term.

```
#!/bin/bash

SEARCH_FILE="/Users/User/Desktop/SEARCH_TEST_2.txt"
RESULTS_FILE="results.txt"
# -i ignores case
GREP_OPTS="-i"

echo "PLEASE ENTER YOUR SEARCH:"

# -r treats backslash as a backslash, instead of an escape character.
read -r sSearchTerms

echo " Searching..."

grep $GREP_OPTS "$sSearchTerms" "$SEARCH_FILE">>"$RESULTS_FILE"

echo " All Done! "

# -t = open with default text editor
open -t "$RESULTS_FILE"

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit' &
exit
```

I'm imagining replacing everything after the

```
read -r sSearchTerms
```

with this:

```
strQuotes='"'
numberOfQuotes=$(grep -o "$strQuotes" <<< "$sSearchTerms" | wc -l)

if [ "$(($numberOfQuotes%2))" != "0" ]
then
    echo "ODD number of quotes"
    # Can't properly parse an odd number of quotes, so Abort!
else
    echo "EVEN number of quotes"
    # We're good to go on quotes, so go ahead and process

    # Create or overwrite the results file
    echo "">"$RESULTS_FILE"

    # CODE HERE to parse input

    # CODE HERE to compare terms to index and build results file
fi

echo " All Done! "
open -t "$RESULTS_FILE"

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit' &
exit
```

For safety and ease of coding, I already test to make sure that the user inputs an even number of quotes (0, 2, 4, ...). If not, I'll just throw a message and make the user try again.

Comment: If the search terms are `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, you want to print only lines that match all of them? In the given order or in any order?

Comment: I want to print lines that match all of the search terms, in any order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Splitting a list of potentially quoted terms into an array of unquoted terms:

Assuming that you don't need to supported *embedded* `"` instances inside `"..."`-quoted search terms, you can use `xargs` to split your list of search terms into individual, unquoted terms, because `xargs` recognizes double-and single-quoted tokens:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prompt the user for a list of potentially quoted search terms.
read -r -p 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR SEARCH: ' termList

# Split the list of terms into an array of unquoted terms.
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra terms < <(xargs printf '%s\n' <<<"$termList")
```

With the sample input (`"Project 32" "audio video" doc`), if you run `declare -p terms` after the above, you get:

```
declare -a terms='([0]="Project 32" [1]="audio video" [2]="doc")'
```

This demonstrates that the list was split into unquoted search terms correctly (the `"` around the element values are not part of the values themselves, they're just an artifact of printing the array's contents with `declare -p`).

---

#### Searching for lines that EACH contain ALL of multiple search terms:

Passing *multiple* search terms to `grep` only supports *disjunctive* logic: any line that matches *any* of those terms matches.

Therefore, you must roll your own *conjunctive* logic, i.e., to match only lines that contain *all* terms.

While you could call `grep` in a loop, that would be inefficient, so `awk` is the better choice:

```
# Search each line of the input file for ALL terms entered and print only
# matching lines.
awk '
  NR==FNR { terms[++i] = $0; next }
  { for(i in terms) { if (index(tolower($0), terms[i]) == 0) next } print }
' <(printf '%s\n' "${terms[@]}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') file
```

Note:

- The above performs *literal* substring matching, as I presume you don't want to support users entering *regular expressions* as search terms.

  - If you do, use the `!~` operator instead of the `index()` call, but be aware that the regex dialect supported by BSD `awk` has fewer features than BSD `grep`'s.
- BSD `awk`, as found on macOS, has the following limitations:

  - Case-insensitive matching is not supported, hence the need to convert both the terms (`tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`) and each input line (`tolower($0)`) to lowercase before matching.
  - Even then, matching will only work with *ASCII-range* characters, because BSD `awk` is not Unicode-aware.

---

If we put it all together:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Determine filenames.
# Note: Better not to use all-uppercase variable names in Bash, because
#       they can conflict with special environment and shell variables.
searchFile="$HOME/Desktop/SEARCH_TEST_2.txt"
resultsFile='results.txt'

# Prompt the user for a list of potentially quoted search terms.
read -r -p 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR SEARCH: ' termList

# Split the list of terms into an array of unquoted terms.
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra terms < <(xargs printf '%s\n' <<<"$termList")

echo 'Searching...'

# Search each line of the input file for ALL terms entered and print only
# matching lines.
awk '
  NR==FNR { terms[++i] = $0; next }
  { for(i in terms) { if (index(tolower($0), terms[i]) == 0) next } print }
' <(printf '%s\n' "${terms[@]}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') "$searchFile" >"$resultsFile"

echo "All Done!" 

open -t "$resultsFile"

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit' &
exit
```

Comment: That is a great use of `xargs` and a *herestring* to separate the terms while preserving quoting. I wouldn't have thought to put those pieces together.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidC.Rankin; using `xargs` to parse quoted strings provided as data is not a common use case, but it does come in handy on occasion.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works beautifully and was well-explained. I appreciate the advice on not using all caps for variable names to avoid potential trouble. I'm thrilled that you incorporated case-insensitive search, too, because I also needed that. I used the following line in my original version to show the number of matches found:

``numMatches=`grep $GREP_opts "$sSearch" "$fileGraphics" | wc -l` ``

It only shows matches for the entire input line as a single search term. Can you show me how to show the number of matches generated when using awk?

Comment: @nollaf126: `wc -l < "$resultsFile"`, run after the `awk` command, will count the number of lines that matched _all_ search terms; or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @mklement0, Great! This makes sense and works fine. I was hoping to be able to  output the number of results at the top of the $resultsFile. In my first version of the search script using grep, I was able to pipe the `wc -l` to the grep command to first get the count, and then I ran the grep again to write the matches to the $resultsFile. The output would be something like _6 results for "cover image"_, followed by a list of all the matches. I would like to be able to show in my $resultsFile the number of matches before listing the matches - without running awk twice. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: @nollaf126: Please ask a _new_ question that is focused just on your follow-up question, and I'll be happy to help (notify me here once you've created the new question).

Answer (score 1):

I don't if this is helpful, but it has a bash function that separates the parameters using quotation marks.

```
#!/bin/bash
work_on_list()
{
  length=$#
  echo "There are $length items"
  for i in {1..1000}
    do
      if [ "$i" -gt "$length" ]
      then
          break
      else
        item=${!i}
        echo "$i  $item"
      fi
    done
}
work_on_list a b "c d" "e f g h" 
work_on_list
work_on_list "This is the first" "second item" "and now the third"
```

The results are

```
There are 4 items
1  a
2  b
3  c d
4  e f g h
There are 0 items
There are 3 items
1  This is the first
2  second item
3  and now the third
```

Comment: Thank you, Bradley Ross! This is a great answer to the first of my two questions. Now if I can just figure out how to compare all of the parsed terms to each line in my text file, I'll be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below that reads a file line by line and runs a regex expression against each line.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 searchline()
 {
 # The following uses the first argument as a regex
 # pattern to test against the second argument.  You
 # can use more complex regex patterns to test for
 # multiple substrings
 if [[ "$2" =~ "$1" ]]
    then
       echo "     String found"
    else
       echo "     String not found"
    fi
 }
 # At this point your read and list the arguments
 args=$#
 echo $args arguments
 echo "list of arguments preceded by script name"
 for i in `seq 0  $args`
    do
       echo "     $i   ${!i}"
    done
 echo "end of arguments"
 # Move the argumnts into the variables
 if [ "$args" -gt 0 ]
    then
       search="$1"
    else
       search="abc"
       echo "Using default search string of abc"
   fi 
 if [ "$args" -gt 1 ]
    then
       file="$2";
    else
       file="stdin"
    fi
 # Read from the file or standard input, runing the 
 # function above against each line
 if [ $file = "stdin" ]
    then
       echo "Read from stdin"
       end_of_file=0
       while [[ $end_of_file == 0 ]]
       do
          read -r line
          end_of_file=$?
          echo $line
          searchline $search $line
       done
    else
       echo "Read from $file"
       IFSold=$IFS
       IFS=$'\n'
       for line in `cat $file`
          do
             echo $line
             searchline $search $line
          done
       IFS=$IFSold
    fi
```

The following was the test file.  It was stored in testiness.txt.  So I ran the
program with the following sets of arguments.

"the" testfiles.txt

"The" testfiles.txt

```
 This is the first line
 Second line
 Now if the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country
 Ignorance of the law is no excuse
 The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```